# iOS -- Conversion of PDF results in saturation of colors

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, core-graphics

we are building up iOS application in which we are converting pdf into png and then we are showing png. PDF to Png conversion is all fine. But there are some problem in saturation of colors.

I also tried to open up the pdf directly in Safari and it results in same saturation of color problems. Is there a way we can control the colors of PDF ?

Following is the code for coversion of pdf page into image:

```
CGRect cropBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFCropBox);
int pageRotation = CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(page);

if ((pageRotation == 0) || (pageRotation == 180) ||(pageRotation == -180)) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropBox.size, NO, resolution / 72); 
}
else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(cropBox.size.height, cropBox.size.width), NO, resolution / 72); 
}

CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   

[PDFPageRenderer renderPage:page inContext:imageContext];

UIImage *pageImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment there is nothing you can do. Probably your PDF files contain CMYK images and iOS does not include a device calibrated CMYK profile so when CMYK is converted to RGB the colors appear quite different.

Comment: Is there any other way with which i can control it? Or is there any tool for linux with which i can convert CMYK pdf into RGB pdf?

Comment: The solution is to convert CMYK pdfs to RGB pdfs. Ghostscript might do the job but I don't know for sure.

Comment: We tried GhostScript but conversion of pdf into RGB compatible PDF results in very slow conversion. IT converts around 3 pages in a minute. Any other way with which we can have fast conversion. Also we came to know that pdf is JPX based pdf. Is this something iOS supports?